# Get Value from Text Box using jquery .aspx page used Master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have pass Id of text box contol  and want to retrive value..

```
  function GetTextval(id) 
        {var value = $('#<%=' + id + '.ClientID %>').val();
         alert(value);
          }
```

Comment: Show how are you using `GetTextval`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call clientId on client-sided variable, you need to pass parameter to function in a way that it is already converted to client id:

```
function GetTextval(id){
  var value = $('#'+id).val();
  alert(value);
}
```

and on calling function:

```
GetTextval(this.id);
```

or

```
GetTextval(<%= ControlId.ClientID %>);
```

Comment: How you are going to pass JavaScript variable to asp.net engine?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#"+<%= id.ClientID %>+"").val();
```

Comment: You have done the same mistake which Zaheer did, see his edits and read my comment under his post